# IOS similler to aar library project in android

Tags: android, ios, aar

I work with android for some time and familiar with the .aar project file which can be created in android studio and wrappes a module with classes and etc.

After that aar is created every project can add it as a mudule dependency and use its method and activities.

In Eclipse that will work as a reference project.

1. My question is how can it be done with IOS?
   I am looking for a way to create some code that existing apps can easily take to their project and use it. looking for directions
2. Say an IOS app can be coded with Objective-c or swift. If I build a code in swift can it be used in both existing codes (objective and swift)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic way to do it is a `static library`.

You build your module in Xcode as a static library, and then, you can link the resulting 'myLib.a' result file to your project using it.

To make it the way iOS/OS X is structured, you make a framework.

`Static framework` are possible before iOS 8 (see this tutorial: https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework)

`Embedded framework` are available since iOS 8 (essentially to allow app extensions). See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

And yes, you can use objective-C framework/library from Swift and Swift framework/library from objective-C code: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 1):

1. In iOS it called `Framework`. [This is a good place to start](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios).
2. Yes. Both ways are available.